# How to make a variable in a class so that all of its methods can access it?

Tags: python, class

I want to make to make `cards[]` an attribute of the class so that when I make the `__str__` methods it can recognize it. Right now this is what it returns:

[image: screenshot of error message]

```
class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        cards = []
        Ranks = ['A', '2', '3', '4','5','6','7','8','9', '10','K', 'Q', 'J']
        Suits = ['♣','♥','♦','♠']
        indexNum = 0
        for i in range(len(Suits)):
            for j in range(len(Ranks)):
                tempCard = PlayingCard(Suits[i],Ranks[j])
                cards+= [tempCard]

                print(cards[indexNum])
                indexNum+=1

    def __str__(self):
        stringOfCards = ''
        x = 1
        while (x<len(cards)):
            myCard =  Deck.cards[x]
            print("this is i")
            print(myCard)
            stringOfCards+="'"+ myCard.rank +"'"+ 'of ' + myCard.suit+", "
            x+=1
        return stringOfCards

deck1 = Deck()
print(deck1)
```

Comment: Inside the for loops and the while loops, instead of `cards`, try replacing with `self.cards`. Not sure if this is the ONLY issue that's stopping your code from working, but try it out.

Comment: You should work through either the [official tutorial chapter on Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), or a friendlier third-party tutorial. Especially if you're coming from another language like Java that has implicit this/self.

Comment: Also where have you defined `PlayingCard`??

Comment: Short answer: In the `__init__()` method, define it as `self.cards = []`, then you'll be able to reference `self.cards` in all the other methods of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Preface all attributes in the `__init__` method with `self.`.

Also, in Python, it is pythonic to use lowercase when referring to variables (e.g. `rank` instead of `Rank`) and to use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`.

e.g.

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = ["4H, 5S"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cards
```

You can then refer to the cards by creating a Deck object, and referring to the cards variable.

```
d = Deck()
d.cards
>> ["4H, "5S"]
```

Comment: I think you mean `self.` :P